# Place order with API IB

Tags: python-3.x, interactive-brokers

After deciding to walk away from Ibpy and learn the API IB I am having trouble even placing an order. What am I doing wrong?

```py
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *




#Def Market Order

class TestApp(EClient, EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        self.nextOrderId = orderId
        print(orderId)
        self.start()


    def start(self):

        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "ES"
        contract.secType = "FUT"
        contract.exchange = "GLOBEX"
        contract.currency = "USD"
        contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "201903"


        order = Order()
        order.action = "BUY"
        order.orderType = "MKT"
        order.totalQuantity = 1
        order.outsideRth = True

        self.placeOrder(self.nextOrderId, contract, order)

    def stop(self):
        self.done = True
        self.disconnect()

def main():
    app=TestApp()
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496,420)
    app.nextOrderId = 0
    app.run()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

removed more Ibpy and replaced with ibapi

now getting

> > > %Run basic.py
> > >       394
> > >       ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
> > >       ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
> > >       ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
> > >       ERROR 394 200 No security definition has been found for the request

Comment: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'conId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order`

Those are from IbPy, use only classes that start with `ibapi`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. So IBAPI doesn't like my Security Definition?

Comment: Don't change the question so the answer becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Your new problem is `contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "201903"
` March is over, use `201909`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Copy and paste isn't the best method.